# What is wrong with configure/make that we need new build tools?

Tags: maven, makefile, ant, gnu-make, bazel

Is make not general enough?

makedepend, autoconf, automake all work to build Makefiles. Is there a flaw in make that causes this type of usage to break down for some languages?

How does ant, Bazel, Maven or other system compile or build a project better than make?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you like to build a Java projects with Make?

Answer (score 1):

`make` come from Unix and is generally good for "if you have X you need to do Y to get Z" one file at a time (like invoking the C compiler on a C source).  All the autoconf/automake/configure tooling is to customize C programs to the actual platform, and is essentially not overlapping with make.

This did not work well for Java as the compiler was fast for compiling multiple files but the overhead of starting the JVM was much too high for compiling one file at a time.  So, a different approach was needed.  First plain javac, then ant (which for all practical purposes is a scripting language), and then maven (which isn't because that was a bad idea).

So, the answer is that different tools arose for different needs.

Comment: I feel like this answer might need to include Bazel because it was asked about